Windows form and user control not working together
Here's the windows forms setup I have

Issue I have is that when I click Expand All / Collapse All buttons my task progresses are not changing size, but when I click Expand / Collapse directly on the task it is working fine even though the function is correctly called which I see from debugging.
Main form > Expand All / Collapse All functions:
private void pbCollapse_Click(object _, EventArgs __) => tasksOverview.SetAllDetailLevels(false);

private void pbExpand_Click(object _, EventArgs __) => tasksOverview.SetAllDetailLevels(true);

Task Overview then successfully calls this function:
public void SetAllDetailLevels(bool increase)
{
    foreach (var control in Controls)
        if (control is TaskProgress)
            ((TaskProgress)control).SetDetailLevel(increase);
}

And then Task Progress is successfully calling first function that calls the second one:
public void SetDetailLevel(bool increase) => SetDetailLevel(_detailLevel + (increase ? 1 : -1));

public void SetDetailLevel(int level)
{
    _detailLevel = level.Clamp(0, MAX_DETAIL_LEVEL);
    pProgress.Visible = _detailLevel > 0;
    pLog.Visible = _detailLevel > 1;
    Refresh();
}

When debugging I see that pProgress.Visible and pLog.Visible do change but I see no changes on screen.
I have no clue how to fix something that's working 'on paper' but not on UI.

I suggest you to subscribe the OnVisibleChanged event of the progress and log control, and add some logs in the event handler to see if the visibility is reverted somehow.

The STUPIDEST thing happened... I had 2 tasksOverview instances, one called tasksOverview and one called tasksOverview1, so I deleted one. I couldn't see one from the other, I stumbled it by chance. Thankfully they were similarly named...
